# iOS background notification handler issue using @react-native-firebase/messaging

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am facing the issue when the app is in background or closed state. The notifications are shown in the notification center in all cases but the `messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler` doesn't get called every time but only some times while checked rigorously on the app. Followed the official documentation for cloud messaging, upgraded to **version 10.2.0** for `@react-native-firebase/messaging` and `@react-native-firebase/app`. All the states callbacks are working fine in **Android** and obtained perfectly every time, the issues exist only for **iOS** and not sure what is causing all this mess.

Adding here code for ref that I am using.
In the entry file i.e. **index.js**

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log("Message handled in the background! 1", remoteMessage);
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }
  return <App />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

In **App.js:**

```
const App = () => {
  var notif = new NotifService();
  useEffect(() => {
    requestUserPermission()
    checkPermission()
    console.log("checkPermission")

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log("A new FCM message arrived!: foreground: ", remoteMessage)
      console.log("A new FCM message arrived!: foreground: ", remoteMessage.messageId)
      // Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!: foreground: ', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      notif.localNotif();
    });
  
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
      Alert.alert('Message handled in the background state!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      // navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
    });
  
    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
          Alert.alert('Message handled in the quit state!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
          // setInitialRoute(remoteMessage.data.type); // e.g. "Settings"
        }
        // setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
  
    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  }

    // 1
    async function checkPermission() {
      const enabled = await messaging().hasPermission();
      console.log("checkPermission: enabled: ", enabled)
      if (enabled) {
        getToken();
      } else {
        requestPermission();
      }
    }
  
    // 3
    async function getToken() {
      let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
      console.log('fcmToken @@1:', fcmToken);
      if (!fcmToken) {
        fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
        console.log('fcmToken @@2:', fcmToken);
        if (fcmToken) {
          // user has a device token
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
        }
      }
    }
  
    // 2
    async function requestPermission() {
      console.log("requestPermission:")
      try {
        await messaging().requestPermission();
        // User has authorised
        getToken();
      } catch (error) {
        // User has rejected permissions
        console.log('permission rejected');
      }
    }
}
```

**Payload** that I tested using firebase rest API:

```
{ "to": "TOKEN_HERE", "data": { "notification": { "title": "ABC1", "body": "xyz1" }, "Name": "121" }, "notification": { "title": "ABC1", "body": "xyz1" }, "priority": "high", "content_available": true }
```

Please add here if anybody faced same issue and resolved that. Stuck for days with this now! Thanks.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score -4):

### Use new API onBackgroundMessage instead

```
Version 7.18.0 - August 13, 2020 Cloud Messaging
Deprecated setBackgroundMessageHandler. Use the new API onBackgroundMessage instead.
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-messaging_2

Comment: These are the docs for firebase cloud messaging JS, not for @react-native-firebase, which has its own setBackgroundMessageHandler API - https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#setBackgroundMessageHandler